# Access local storage in angular universal

Tags: angular6, angular-universal

I have my angular universal app running well. But few of the libraries which I use, internally uses localStorage to set and get data. I can neither omit the libraries nor change it. Being said that, is there a workaround where I can use localStorage in server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use
node-localstorage npm module to use localStorage at the nodejs server side.

Comment: const LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage;
(global as any).localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch');